# Javascript : If statement using a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this If statement which is supposed to return more than one result but the instruction code is only executed once:

```
var regex1 = /[\S]{2,3}[1|2|3]/;

for (let j = 0; j < notes.length; j++) { 
    if (regex1.exec(data[i])==notes[j][0]) {
        // code to be executed
    }
}
```

`notes[j][0]` is made of elements like: `aa1`, `ab2`, ... It works fine when my `data[i]` is `aa1` but if it looks like `aa1ab2` it only works for `aa1` and doesn't execute the code for another round for `ab2`. Do I have a regex issue (I've tested it on a regex tester and it seemed to work just fine) or is the `if` statement causing problems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put a `g` at the end of your regex. `g` is a global modifier that will return more than one match.

```
/[\S]{2,3}[1|2|3]/g
```